# Play2 - encode special characters in request with WSClient

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, urlencode

I am calling one application from other application using Play WSClient.

```
    parameter q value 'hello & hi' is encoded as 'hello%20%26%20hi'
    String requestString = "http://localhost:9000/query?q=hello%20%26%20hi" 
    F.Promise<WSResponse> response = WS.url(requestString).get();
```

When the request is received at other application.
q parameter value would become 'hello '

If the same request is executed from browser, then its working fine and q parameter value would be 'hello & hi'. But from play WSClient it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Play, report it.

Comment: Thanks. I am using activator 1.2.10, will check it in other versions too.

Comment: Btw, resolved this issue by using setQueryParameter.